# How to run a command as specific user without switching(su)

Tags: shell

I want to run a specific set of commands as 'oracle' user from ldap user 'exp'

for example:

```
exp@linuxtest -]$ sudo -u oracle \"export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle;echo $ORACLE_HOME;export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin;$ORACLE_HOME/bin/exp full=y
```

I tried above command, getting following error

```
usage: sudo [-D level] -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-D level] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user name|#uid]
usage: sudo -l[l] [-AknS] [-D level] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-U user name] [-u user name|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid] [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C fd] [-D level] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user name|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
```

In the end, i want to run the following command as 'oracle' user without switching to oracle user. Because switching to oracle user requires password which gives full access as 'oracle' user to 'exp' user.

```
sudo su - oracle -c \"export ORAENV_ASK=NO;export ORACLE_SID=`ps -ef |grep pmon |grep -v grep | grep pmon | grep -v asm| grep -v APX | awk -F_ '{print $3}'`;export ORACLE_HOME="`cat /etc/oratab |grep dbhome | awk -F: '{print $2}' |sort  -u |sed -e /^$/d`";export ORACLE_SID=`ps -ef |grep pmon |grep -v grep | grep pmon | grep -v asm| grep -v APX | awk -F_ '{print $3}'`;export PATH=$PATH:"`cat /etc/oratab |grep dbhome | awk -F: '{print $2}' |sort  -u |sed -e /^$/d`"/bin:"`cat /etc/oratab |grep dbhome | awk -F: '{print $2}' |sort  -u |sed -e /^$/d`"/OPatch;"/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin/expdp  \"sys/oracle as sysdba\" DIRECTORY=DATAPUMP_DIR dumpfile=FULL_DB.dmp FULL=Y LOGFILE=full_exp.log"\"
```

Comment: are you sure that it is the full error message? by the way: you should mask the inner quotes of commands, not the outer most ones

Comment: Do you have a command already installed named `oraenv ` that can set those environment variables for you?

Answer (score 4):

You're in quoting hell.  Try this: using sudo, lauch a shell, and feed that shell commands from a here-doc. This version you can actually read:

```
sudo -u oracle -c sh <<'END_SH'
    export ORAENV_ASK=NO
    export ORACLE_SID=$(pgrep -fl pmon | grep -Eiv 'asm$|apx$' | cut -d_ -f3)
    export ORACLE_HOME=$(awk -F: '/dbhome/ {print $2}' /etc/oratab |sort  -u)
    export PATH="$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$ORACLE_HOME/OPatch"

    "$ORACLE_HOME"/bin/expdp  "sys/oracle as sysdba" DIRECTORY=DATAPUMP_DIR dumpfile=FULL_DB.dmp FULL=Y LOGFILE=full_exp.log
END_SH
```

I simplified your grep|grep|awk pipelines quite a bit. I don't understand why you're using `sort` when setting ORACLE_HOME: are you expecting `dbhome` to appear multiple times in /etc/oratab?